# Read/Write data from Beacon using USB cable

Tags: javascript, node.js, usb, ibeacon, beacon

My beacon use the iBeacon protocol so I need two things :

How to read the data (proximity uuid, major, minor, tx power , mac address, ect ... ) from the beacon by connect it to PC with usb cable and also the write mode e.g change the major or minor for example ?

Is there any way or library to do that in node.js ?

Answer (score 1):

Understand that the iBeacon standard only defines the beaconing transmission format of a bluetooth device.  **There is no specification for how is is to be configured.**  What this means is that every manufacturer of a beacon that transmits the iBeacon standard packet has a different way of configuring the beacon.

Since there is no standard way to do this, you have to ask you manufacturer how you do this.  Many manufacturers support doing this with a mobile app, some provide a mobile SDK to do it.  I have not heard of any manufacturers providing a public way to configure beacons over a USB interface. While it is possible that some manufacturers support this, it is not likely that yours does.  **The most likely answer is that you cannot configure your beacon programmatically over USB.**  If you can update your question with the manufacturer, it is possible that an alternative may be available.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, I'll update my question if I got more information from the manufacturer

Answer (score 0):

You could look for a specific node lib wrote for/by iBeacon on npm.

Otherwise you should find some API that describes their serial protocol and try to make a lib using https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport